# Show two differents values from the same field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

HI, i have two tables
1- name, id, code
2- id, value, concept

One name can have two concepts and two values. i want to retreive this:
Id, name, value1, value2.

How can i do that?

Tanks

Comment: What field is used to link tables 1 and 2? Or is the id the common key?

Comment: Please clarify this question. It sounds like you want to perform a JOIN operation on the two tables, joining by id.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a start:

```
SELECT
    T.id,
    T.name,
    V1.value AS value1,
    V2.value AS value2
FROM
    My_Table T
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Values V1 ON V1.id = T.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Values V2 ON V1.id = T.id
```

But the question here is, what differentiates value 1 from value 2? Is it a value in "concept", is it a matter of which was added to the DB first? Which has a higher id column for some other column? Your requirements are not fully spelled out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do for example

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.value as value1, t2.value as value2
FROM table2 as t
     INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t.id = t2.id AND t.value <> t2.value
```

but there are many other ways available.

EDIT

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2a.value as value1, t2b.value as value2
FROM table1 as t 
     INNER JOIN table2 as t2a ON t.id = t2a.id
     INNER JOIN table2 as t2b ON t.id = tba.id AND t2b.value <> t2a.value
```

Note: solution assumes that there are 2 rows per id (in case of 3 rows you will get multiple rows per id in the results)

Comment: looks good except you are only using the second table he mentioned and the 'name' column is in the first table. The only thing I would add is do another join with table1 as t1 on table1.id = table2.id so he would have the name field as t1.name